# How can a user select the language for the webchat?

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, developer, chat, deployment-api

I'm creating a webchat for a Canadian company. They want the ability for the user to select (in pre-chat) the language: either French or English.
Once the user selects the language, he/she can fill in the pre-chat details, and then an Einstein Bot takes over.

I'm struggling to find a way to have the user select the language and based on that show different pre-chat questions and have a different Einstein bot (in the appropriate language) to take over.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this for one of my clients. The solution is not intuitive *at all*. What you have to do is create a separate bot to serve as your "language router". Connect that bot to the button config that's used in your deployment (classic deployment or snap-ins/embedded service).

In the bot, you have to read in the data from pre-chat. You can do that by writing the pre-chat data to the transcript, then use a Flow or Apex to read the data from the transcript into the bot. See here for a basic example of how this works: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_optimize_flow_lex.htm

Once you have that data in the bot, you can use a "Rule" element in your Welcome dialog to manipulate the routing. You can route directly from bot-to-bot in this manner using the customer's selected language as the condition.